# Ultimate way to host webapplications

Tags: performance, amazon-web-services, hosting, scalability, load-balancing

I know this topic was widely discussed all over the Internet, but as an amateur in these matters I dare to ask my question.

I am looking for a flexible solution to host my webapplications. Flexible means that it would be sufficient for any kind of project - **small website and Reddit-scale giant**.

So far, I was thinking this way: I start with shared hosting, then my website get more and more popular so I buy a VPS, then dedicated server, then people finally notice how amazing my idea is and I have to build my own datacenter.

Currently, I am in the stage when I am moving my webapps from several shared hostings to VPS and it got me thinking - is there a better, more comfortable solution? I do not want to move to another hosting, constantly upgrade my hosting plan and still be worrying about performance.

But there is a service like Amazon AWS (and some others), which promise to provide me with comfortable solution to the problem. They say I will be charged only for what I have used **and, by enabling auto-scaling, my apps will be growing with (almost) no limits.** But most importantly, I would not have to worry about building my own infrastructure etc.
Of course, service like this still requires management, but as far as I am concerned it would be a task to rather small team or even one person. (Right?)

Reddit is a great example of what I am talking about. One of the most popular website on the Internet is **100% hosted by AWS**.

So my question is: **Is service like AWS the dream platform for entrepreneurs who are willing to create "something big"?** Is it the most flexible and the most comfortable solution there is? What are disadvantages I do not see?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my experience a dedicated server gives you a lot of wiggle room, I use it for big webapps that do a lot of data crunching, but also small websites.

If you have a decent multi cpu server with a lot of RAM and large high speed sata 3 SSD's and fiberoptic network for top speed, your server will be blazing away.

If you use a linux based server it will become easy to cluster them.

Then when you need even more speed you can just put the SQL server in an own dedicated server and you will have doubled your speed instantly.
SQL servers cluster easily among multiple computers so there will be room to grow, and linux servers also cluster easily(at least for people who know what they are doing).

I totally recommend having your own dedicated service where you decide how it grows, then to be stuk on someone elses turf and to get pinched in speed when a high paying customer needs premium speed.

Just my 2 cents

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Do you know why companies like Reddit or Tumblr went cloud instead of investing in their own intrastructure?

Comment: Their focus was probaly on programming. Like the guy who made Tumblr dropped out of high school at age 15, wanted to do something with the internet and programming and just started away hacking his software together.
No highschool, no college == no idea what goes on in the world, and lo, behold, a cloud provider gave a friendly price and we went for it. If you look at business wise it will be better to build your own cloud. That way you control how what happens and how fast and big it is, and you can make performance tweaks.

Comment: So AWS IS the most attractive offer for small team without big resources and with big plans? We lose some control and our independence, but gain comfort and peace of mind?

Comment: @MichaelDibbets I don't quite agree with the "always build your own cloud" mentality. Certain use cases it works very well. Others, like in the case of Tumblr and Reddit, need certain benefits not offered within a private cloud. Immediate scalability for websites with billions of unique monthly views and user created content will not be maintained easily or cost effectively on a private cloud. Also "no highschool, no college" really has nothing to do with Tumblr's infrastructure.

Comment: @Testeross, I suggest you take a look at [the Reddit study](http://goo.gl/W6ZGc). Mind you this is published by AWS so it's a little gimmicky. There is no real dream platform. It's going to be a case by case thing. If you REALLY need the flexibility that you say you do, eventually a cloud based platform will make the most sense cost wise.

Comment: Also after reading [this blog post](http://highscalability.com/blog/2012/2/13/tumblr-architecture-15-billion-page-views-a-month-and-harder.html) I'm going foot in mouth when it comes to Tumblr. Interesting read!